# Automatic manipulation of data in Oracle with Jupyter Notebook (Windows & OS X)

Tags: python, oracle, jupyter-notebook

I have a table with 5 columns and an empty column in oracle. I am searching for a way to pull that table from Oracle, use it in the Jupyter Notebook to add data in that empty column (through executing the python script) and then INSERT the table into Oracle again.

I know i could just export the table from Oracle manually, run it through the notebook and use the import in Oracle manually, but i am searching for a way that i could do all those steps as an automatic daily job.

I am using both windows and OS x, so it would be cool if there would be both solutions to this problem.

Best regards & thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using 'cx_Oracle' module.

Below link has the example usage:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Comment: Yes, that is probably a good start. Do you know how i could do the automatization?

Comment: For cx_Oracle info, also see the more recent tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Comment: @AdamJensen: Automating it depends on the scale of usage. At the simplest considering it scheduling on 'Windows Scheduler'. You can control the time/days your scripts needs to run.